# Group objects list by Dictionary value

Tags: c#, list, linq

I've list of object which looks like below

```
public class test
{
  public int ID{ get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, string> SampleXML { get; set; }
}
```

I want to group the list based on values in 'SampleXML'. e.g. It contains values like price. I want to group List based on price.

How to implement the same. I tried below code but it just seperates the list by key. I need unique records.

```
Dictionary<string, List<test>> result = Obj.LstTest
  .GroupBy(x => x.SampleXML["Price"])
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                g => g.ToList());
```

The above code generates the list based on price. e.g. If there are 6 records with 3 different prices, above code return 3 results,but again the list contains two records each.

**EDIT**

If the price is blank then it needs to be ignored in grouping that is if there are 3 records and all doesn't have prices then list will contain 3 item(as it is).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Change `g.ToList()` to `g.FirstOrDefault()` and the result should be a `Dictionary<string, test> result`

Comment: I'm confused, you say you want to group things by price. In your example you have 6 items with 3 distinct prices that are grouped into 3 groups of two each. This doesn't seem to be what you want though... What exactly do you want as the output? Perhaps you should provide sample input and output to make it clear what you want? eg do you just want to sort the list so that items of the same price are together in the list? You clearly don't want it actually split into groups if I am reading you correctly...

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your response. List contains 6 items. Lets say item1 and item2 has price $2,item3 and item4 has price $3,item5 and item6 has price $4. Now the resultant list will contain list with 3 items e.g. item1,item3 and item5. Let me know if its still not clear so that i can update question if needed.

Comment: @user2645738: How do you choose which of items one and two you want to include or does it not matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Only focus is that item should not get repeated based on price. I forgot to mention ,if price is blank(string.empty) then it should also get included into result.

Comment: Why is the class test defined as Dictionary<string, string> instead of Dictionary<string, List<string>>

Comment: @user2645738, do you mean **include** or **remove** all tests with null/empty price key?

Comment: @BassemAkl Include the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Based on Vicky S edit**
To still have the result as a List of test:

```
List<test> list = new List<test>();
List<test> result = new List<test>();
result = list.GroupBy(x => x.SampleXML["Price"]).Select(g=>g.FirstOrDefault());
```

**Edit:** To include tests that have SampleXML with empty Price value or no Price Key. Do the following:

First we need to separate tests with "No Price" and include them to our final result, from test that have "Price" value to group them.

```
 var emptyPrice = list.Where(l => !l.SampleXML.ContainsKey("Price") || l.SampleXML["Price"] == string.Empty).ToList();
 var withoutEmptyPrice = list.Where(l => l.SampleXML.ContainsKey("Price") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.SampleXML["Price"]));
```

Then we will group tests with "Price" value as my first answer.

```
var resultWithEmptyPrice = withoutEmptyPrice.GroupBy(x => x.SampleXML["Price"]).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Finally, we will add the "No Price" tests to our result.

```
resultWithEmptyPrice.AddRange(emptyPrice);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is working,but would you please tell me how to get final result as List<test> rather than Dictionary<string, test>?

Comment: This still gives me Dictionary. Is there anyway i can get only List<test> as a final output(resultList)

Comment: @user2645738, now you have a List of test. And my apologies to Vicky S, because I canceled his correct edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This worked exactly as what is expected. Thanks a lot. Would you please review the edit i made to the question. I came across this while implementing the code you provided. It works in cases where all the prices are available,but it gives me a single result if all the data doesn't contain price.